# Is it "look in the eye" or "look in the eyes"

Tags: idioms

Is it "look in the eye" or "look in the eyes"? Or are they both correct. For example in russian eyes are always plural in literal meaning and when used as idiom (be able to look at somebody directly (because you dont feel embarrassed, ashamed, etc.)). On one hand idea of looking in just one eye is odd, on the other hand it's obvious that person can't look at two objects simultaneously, it's not how vision works.

Comment: Could you give some more explanation of what the Russian idiom means?

Comment: Voting to close as Unclear. We don't even know if OP is asking about usages relating to *The look in her eye was murderous* (often pluralised to ***eyes***) or *He could not look her in the eye* (almost never pluralised).

Comment: @FumbleFingers From the last sentence I would infer it's the latter.

Comment: @OliverMason: *You know the old saying [“Look me in the eyes and say that!”*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22look+me+in+the+eyes+and+say+that%22)

Comment: ...vastly outnumbered in Google Books by [*Look me in the **eye** and say that*,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22look+me+in+the+eye+and+say+that%22) though.

Comment: And I would argue that that would be the literal eyes! :) [the plural one]

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey,@FumbleFingers I edited question to clarify the case, thanks

Comment: @FumbleFingers yeah I had a peek at NGrams which has 'look me in the eye' much higher. I'm not sure if it's wrongly counting 'look me in the eyes' though

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: You could have saved me some trouble if you'd copied the NGram link into your comment (Fer Chrissakes! I put **both** my Google Books links in, even though you'd only have to delete just one character from the first to reproduce the second! :) Anyway, for the benefit of anyone else who may be interested, [here it is](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=look+me+in+the+eye%2Clook+me+in+the+eyes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clook%20me%20in%20the%20eye%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clook%20me%20in%20the%20eyes%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oops yeah that would have been better of me, sorry :)

Comment: ...which meant there wasn't enough space in the comment for me to actually *comment* on it! What I see is that the singular has apparently shot to prominence (on both sides of the pond; I did check, but you can do it yourself if you want! :) only over the last 3-4 decades. Before that the alternative was reasonably common, though declining from a much earlier period of "idiomatic traction equivalence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English this is often the difference between literal and idiomatic use.

*He couldn't look her in the eye* means something like "He was too ashamed/embarrassed to talk to her", whereas *He couldn't look her in the eyes* means he was not tall enough, or she had her eyes closed.

Another well-know idiom is *Beauty is in the eye of the beholder*. Again it's the more abstract use of *eye* as opposed to the physical visual organ.

So, both are correct, but in idiomatic use only the singular would be right.